# Is the set of countable successor ordinals countable or uncountable?

Tags: set-theory, ordinals

I know that $\omega_1$={$\alpha$ : $\alpha$ is a countable ordinal} is uncountable but what about the subset of $\omega_1$ of countable successor ordinals?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** There is an obvious bijection taking $\omega_1$ to the successor ordinals therein.

**Hint 2:** To be a successor ordinal is to be in the image of ...?

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:**
Assume that it is countable; and take $\alpha=\sup\{\beta\mid\beta\text{ is a countable successor ordinal}\}$. Show that $\alpha$ is countable. Now, what can you say about $\alpha+1$? Conclude a contradiction.